# slides in wordpress child theme flashing images

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am pretty new to Wordpress. I have customized a page with Helix theme through a child theme: 
http://test.thres.com 
In the original (Helix theme) the transitions are smooth and nice but in my version they are flashing. Is it possible that the page is loaded twice, once for the original theme and one for the customization in the child? The original theme has 2 css-files. I have imported both themes, style.css and theme.css by this functions.php code:

`<?php 
    function wpse_load_parent_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/theme.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_parent_stylesheets' );
?>`

Any idea of what goes wrong?

Thanks for your attention.
Best,
Masreliez

Comment: The page is not loaded twice, but it's possible there's a css conflict. What happens if you remove the files, one by one? Try increasing the speed in cycleOptions to see if the flash happens at a certain interval or slower.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the slides, nothing changes. Then I tried to speed it up with only two slides and the flash disappeared. I increased the speed/timeout from 500/1000 to 2000/2000. However, I changed this in the theme js-code. How can I make the js changes in my child theme/without affecting updates from the original theme? Thanks for your attention/Masreliez

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. I always create my own themes from scratch and disable all updates for WP and plugins because updates have already lead to more work for me and frustration for the customer. Sometimes, people request the solution to be so specific that I have to modify the plugin source and then I can't allow updates or those changes would be lost.